# ODR Exception 'NSBundleResourceRequest could not connect to its helper daemon'

Tags: ios, xcode, cocoa-touch, on-demand-resources

I am getting random crash in my in-market app that I believe caused by ODR. And It looks like I am not the only who encountered it, I found this [radar](https://openradar.appspot.com/34389684) and this [thread](https://forums.developer.apple.com/thread/52518) but neither of them seem to have a fix for the issue. I am hoping somebody here have encountered this issue and found a fix for it, or a repro steps would be helpful too because I cannot reproduce it

[image: Stack trace]

Comment: Our app also experiences similar random crashes. We've done much experimenting, we've opened an issue with Apple developer support - they suggested a few things and nothing worked. We believe this is a bug in iOS that Apple is simply too lazy (or busy) to fix for many years. We live with this for now, but we are considering ditching ODR for good.

Comment: @serge_o in order to mitigate or eliminate this issue we created a serial queue that executes async process when calling the process of requesting the On Demand Resource. 

I still believe this is something Apple should control but we did that in the meantime and no crashes happen even having 1000 threads calling for different resources at the same time. I will try to leave a code example later today in this thread.

Comment: We also perform all NSBundleResourceRequest calls on a serial queue but are still running in this issue (it’s our top crash on iOS).

Comment: I am seeing this issue occur consistently as well. It is the top crash on iOS